# problem with saving data in many-to-many intermediate table spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

following are my entity

```
package bt.gov.dit.inventoryservice.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
//import org.hibernate.mapping.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "items")

public class Items implements Serializable  {


    private Long Id;

    @Column(name = "item_name")
    private String itemName;

    //    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id",nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Categories categories;


    private Stores stores;

    //@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "insert_date")
    private Date insertDate = new Date();

   // @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "update_date")
    private Date updateDate = new Date();


    private Set<Logs> logs = new HashSet<Logs>() ;




    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Categories getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Categories categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stores_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Stores getStores() {

        return stores;
    }

    public void setStores(Stores stores) {

        this.stores = stores;
    }

    public Date getInsertDate() {
        return insertDate;
    }

    public void setInsertDate(Date insertDate) {
        this.insertDate = insertDate;
    }

    public Date getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "items_logs", joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "items_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "logs_id",referencedColumnName = "id") )
    public Set<Logs> getLogs() {
        return logs;
    }

    public void setLogs(Set<Logs> logs) {
        this.logs = logs;
    }


}
```

```
package bt.gov.dit.inventoryservice.model;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;


import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "logs")
public class Logs {


    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "cadet_id")
    private Long cadetId;


    private Set<Items> items = new HashSet<Items>() ;

    @Column(name = "borrowed_date")
    //@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date borrowedDate = new Date();

    private String status;

    private String comments;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getCadetId() {
        return cadetId;
    }

    public void setCadetId(Long cadetId) {
        this.cadetId = cadetId;
    }



    public Date getBorrowedDate() {
        return borrowedDate;
    }

    public void setBorrowedDate(Date borrowedDate) {
        this.borrowedDate = borrowedDate;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "logs")
    public Set<Items> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Set<Items> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

I have many to many relationship between them. Due to that there is an intermediate table created with field item_id and log_id. Now I don't know how to save data in that table. I can save items and i can save log. But I have problem with saving the many-to-many relationship between them?

Comment: Hi, I do believe it will be a lot easier for you to get help if you share the problem you're having. Such as error logs for instance.

Comment: Hi, can you add also the code you're using to add data to your database? Are you using entityManager or a JpaRepository?

Comment: @MarcosBarbero there is no error

Comment: @A.Wolf I have just extended JpaRepository . no code there

Comment: It's difficult to help you if you don't add the full code :) how are you setting the relationship for example? Please add also other classes.